# Problems try encode entity to json

Tags: json, serialization, entity, symfony-2.3

im try encode an Doctrine entity as JSON string, to send as Ajax response.
So, i check the doc: [The Serializer Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

I try with this code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
// Get the entities repository
$sesiones_registradas = $em->getRepository('AuditBundle:AuditSession')->findAll();

// Instance the object
$serializer = new Serializer(array(new JsonEncoder()),array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()));

// Convert only an item
foreach($sesiones_registradas as $sesion){
    echo $serializer->normalize($sesion,'json');
    break;
}
// Stop script
die();
```

Last code, fails saying:

> Could not normalize object of type
>   AppsManantiales\AuditBundle\Entity\AuditSession, no supporting
>   normalizer found.

And if change `$serializer->normalize($sesion,'json')` by `$serializer->serialize($sesion, 'json');` The error message is:

> Serialization for the format json is not supported

Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JMS Serializer Bundle

The docs can be found here: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle

Answer (score 3):

Your problem come from the fact you **inverted** both `normalizers` and `encoders`.

The line:
`$serializer = new Serializer(array(new JsonEncoder()),array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()));`
must be:
`$serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array(new JsonEncoder()));`