# Symfony Serializer doesn't deserialize into objects in different namespace: 'no supporting normalizer found'

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize json into an object using the packages symfony/serializer and symfony/property-access through composer. It works when the class I'm deserializing into is in the same file, but not when it's somewhere else (not even a different file in the same namespace).
I have the following code:

```
<?php // Somewhere/Foo.php
namespace Somewhere;
class Foo
{
    private $foo;
    public function getFoo() { return $this->foo; }
    public function setFoo($foo) { $this->foo = $foo; }
}
```

And:

```
<?php // file tests/Test.php
namespace tests;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Somewhere\Foo;

class Foo2
{
    private $foo;
    public function getFoo() { return $this->foo; }
    public function setFoo($foo) { $this->foo = $foo; }
}

class Test extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testFoo()
    {
        $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer(), new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        $payload = '{"foo": {"bar": "baz"}}';

        $obj = $serializer->deserialize($payload, Foo::class, 'json');
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Foo::class, $obj);
    }

    public function testFoo2()
    {
        $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer(), new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        $payload = '{"foo": {"bar": "baz"}}';

        $obj = $serializer->deserialize($payload, Foo2::class, 'json');
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Foo2::class, $obj);
    }
}
```

The test using the local class (`Foo2`) works fine, but the one using the class in a different namespace (`\Somewhere\Foo`) shows me this error:
`Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\UnexpectedValueException: Could not denormalize object of type Somewhere\Foo, no supporting normalizer found`.

I've tried using `\Somewhere\Foo::class`, `'Foo'` and `'\Somewhere\Foo'` instead of Foo::class too without any luck.

Similar Questions:

- [Serializing and Deserializing in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831133/serializing-and-deserializing-in-symfony) marks one answer which uses strings as correct but not really, if you read the comments you'll see it didn't really solved the question.
- [Could not denormalize object of type, no supporting normalizer found. Symfony 2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576832/could-not-denormalize-object-of-type-no-supporting-normalizer-found-symfony-2) In the comments the OP says using `ClassName::class` worked, but this doesn't work for me.
- [Problems try encode entity to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953802/problems-try-encode-entity-to-json) The answer was to stop using `symfony/serializer` and use `jms/serializer` instead. Is it really not possible with Symfony's serializer?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because `Foo` class doesn't exists in this context, you've probably forgotten to include this file `Somewhere/Foo.php` to autoload.

In your sample this should work!

```
<?php // file tests/Test.php

namespace tests;

include 'Somewhere/Foo.php';

//...
```

Some editors as PHPStorm are able to auto-import the `Foo` class if it's in the same directory without show any error.

Comment: Yes, I added it to composer's autoloader and now it works. Thanks!